# Balancing a campaign for newbie and veteran players alike

Tags: new-players, balance, problem-players, group-dynamics

So I'm running my first custom world campaign.  This will be the first full campaign I've run, and I'm a little nervous.

The party consists of 4 complete newbies, and my partner who's a veteran player - who's built a warlock which by level 8 could take out small countries (I've been assured that he won't do as such).

But how am I supposed to balance fights where half the players can barely be tell the difference between a D12 and a D20, and the other can use self destructing mouselings as weapons?

Comment: What system are you using?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to RPG.stackexchange.com! Unfortunately, we need to know more about your problem to reliably help you, namely we would like you to name the system that you are using: plenty of role-playing games have D12, D20 and Warlocks. Your question has been put on hold, so nobody gives you a useless answer before you specify the system. Good luck, and waiting for your response!